# Is there a function similar to MATLAB's ismember in R?

Tags: r, matlab, function

Is there ONE function in R which gives out a similar output to MATLAB's `ismember()` if I want a logical array and the indexes of locations where the array elements are members of set array.

Matlab code:

```
A = [5 3 4 2]; 
B = [2 4 4 4 6 8]; 
[la loc] = ismember(A,B)
```

Output:

```
la = 1x4 logical array
   0   0   1   1

loc = 

     0     0     2     1
```

To get a similar output in R right now I use this:

```
ismember <- function(A,B){

        out <- match(A,B)
        out <- cbind(out,(A %in% B)*1)
        out[is.na(out)] <- 0

}

ismember(A,B)
```

Output:

```
     out  
[1,]   0 0
[2,]   0 0
[3,]   2 1
[4,]   1 1
```

Comment: Please detail better what is the expected output

Comment: It could be written as one line like this: `cbind(A %in% B, match(A, B, nomatch = 0))`

Comment: `is.element`  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Matlab function `ismember` can be translated to R in [two ways](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/sets):

- `is.element`
- `%in%`

hence:

```
ismember(A,B) ---> is.element(A, B)
ismember(A,B) ---> A %in% B
```

If you want to include indexing, you can use the [match function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/match):

```
loc <- match(A, B)
print(loc)

   [1] NA NA 2 1
```

By default, when using `match`, values with no match return `NA` but you can change this behavior through the `nomatch` parameter:

```
loc <- match(A, B, nomatch = 0)
print(loc)

   [1] 0 0 2 1
```

In conclusion, your Matlab code:

```
A = [5 3 4 2]; 
B = [2 4 4 4 6 8];

[la,loc] = ismember(A,B);
```

can basically be translated to:

```
A <- c(5,3,4,2)
B <- c(2,4,4,4,6,8)

la <- is.element(A, B)
loc <- match(A, B, nomatch = 0)
```

If you want to obtain both values combined into a single variable you could use:

```
res <- cbind.data.frame(la = is.element(A, B), loc = match(A, B, nomatch = 0))

print(res$la)
   [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

print(res$loc)
   [1] 0 0 2 1
```